# Restful webservice with jaxb annotations on model class returns HTTP 415 unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb

I have a Java springboot existing rest webservice which has `@Produces(application/json)`, `@consumes(application/json)` and model classes with jaxb annotations `@XmlType (propOrder=..)`.
When i call this webservice with postman json data, I get HTTP status code `415 unsupported media type`. I found that some Property is present in model class but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder. Is it mandatory that all fields should be present in propOrder? (Queues also use the same model classes without any issue).

Comment: What Content-Type are you sending?

Comment: I have application/json for content type. That was the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in documentation: "propOrder annotation on a class to specify content order, all public properties and public fields in the class must be specified in the parameter list."
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnbdb/index.html